# hover on an <img> to make a new div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have it so that when I hover on an `<img>` tag, a div will appear over it. I want it to be a white overlay with text inside of it.

I cannot make the image a background-image, as much as I would like to. My code uses width:percent/max-width:pixels and height:auto/max-height:pixels, so without the img there, nothing would show up. And to my knowledge, there is no solution to that issue.

I attempted to give the image a unique id and apply a id:hover .class to have the div appear, but it didn't respond to any coding I gave it, let alone work right. I then tried putting the id on a div of its own over putting it on the picture with still no yield.

I also tried to make a div with the image as a background pic and made the hover as desired. I tried to make the div not implode by putting in another div that has the image constraints, but because of the height:auto, it didn't work.

I refuse to set height/width as pixels, as it would mess up the rest of my coding and one of the major reasons I'm coding what I am. So, if it's not possible because of this, that's fine; Just tell me.

My CSS is as follows:

```
#logo { 
    text-align: center;
    width:100%;
    max-width:769px;
    height:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#bannerpic {
    max-width:769px;
    max-height:300px;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}

#bannerpic .logobody {
    display:none;
}

#bannerpic:hover .logobody {
    display:inline;
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

My HTML is this:

```
<div id="logo">
    <img id="bannerpic" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/67673862/logoTEMP.png">
        <div class="logobody">text</div>
    </img>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you need to be able to click the image, but you can overlay text with absolute positioning.

```css
#logo {
    text-align: center;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 469px;
}

#bannerpic {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.logobody {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: pink;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .3s;
    transition: opacity .3s;
}

.logobody:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="logo">
    <img id="bannerpic" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/67673862/logoTEMP.png" />
    <div class="logobody">text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, the image doesn't need to be clickable. This worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
#logo {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.logobody {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#logo:hover .logobody{
  visibility: visible;
}

#bannerpic {
    max-width:769px;
    max-height:300px;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

Here's a JSFiddle link for it:

https://jsfiddle.net/zVBDc/790/embedded/result/

**Note**: My example is using 0.75 alpha for the background. 0.5 seemed too low. Set it to whatever you prefer, though.